# Powershell folder creation from variables

Tags: powershell

Here's what I have working so far:

```
$extensions = '*.xls*', '*.doc*', '*.txt', '*.pdf', '*.jpg', '*.lnk', '*.pub', '*.pst', '*.pps', '*.ppt'

Get-Content C:\computers.txt | % {
  $ComputerName = $_

  $dst = "\\Server\share\$ComputerName"
  $src = "\\$ComputerName\c$\Documents and Settings\**\Desktop",
         "\\$ComputerName\c$\Documents and Settings\**\My Documents"

  New-Item -ItemType Directory $dst

  Get-Childitem $src -Include $extensions -Recurse -Force |
    Copy-Item -Destination $dst\
}
```

My goal is to back up specific file types from a list of machines. These machines have approx 10-20 profiles on them. Would it be possible to arrange these files in a directory under the computer name directory from the profile they came from? Such as creating a profile name directory under the created computer name directory then dump the targeted files in their appropriate folder.

Example:

```
\\server\share\computername1\profile1\document.doc
\\server\share\computername2\Profile2\document.doc
```

Comment: I'd like to add a comment for anyone needing to know what the current PS script does.  It searches a list of machines for specific file types then creates a directory named after the machine they came from and puts those files in those computer name directories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use wildcards in your source paths if you want to use part of the path (well, technically you can, but it'd be a pain in the rear). Use an inner loop instead:

```
$extensions = '*.xls*', '*.doc*', ...

Get-Content C:\computers.txt | % {
  $ComputerName = $_

  Get-ChildItem "\\$ComputerName\c$\Documents and Settings" | ? {
    $_.PSIsContainer
  } | % {
    $dst = Join-Path "\\Server\share\$ComputerName" $_.Name

    New-Item -ItemType Directory $dst
    # no need to create $dst first, b/c New-Item will auto-create missing
    # parent folders

    $src = (Join-Path $_.FullName 'Desktop'),
           (Join-Path $_.FullName 'My Documents')

    Get-Childitem $src -Include $extensions -Recurse -Force |
      Copy-Item -Destination $dst\
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is close!  It's creating the profile folders, but it's still placing the files under the root machine name directory instead of placing the files under the profile they were found in.

Comment: @user3407887: My bad. Construction of `$dst` needs to be moved inside the loop too.

Comment: @user3407887: I already updated my answer accordingly. If you click on the "edited xx mins ago" link below it you'll see a side-by-side comparison of the changes I made.

Comment: Sorry about that, I just now noticed.  It works!  Thanks again, saves me a tons of time with this.